# Replacement for Mongoid::Paranoia

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

Browsing through the Mongoid documentation, I saw that the [`Mongoid::Paranoia` extra](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/extras.html#paranoia) will disappear in version 4.

Why is this?

What can be used to replace `Mongoid::Paranoia` and keep a similar behaviour?

Comment: Hope this answer [it](https://github.com/simi/mongoid-paranoia) perhaps there looking to what rails core team is doing segregate and let developer what they need

Comment: @Viren Thanks for the link, that's interesting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's where the decision was made: https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/2433. The intent was explicitly to make it an externally-provided dependency. Looks like there are already a couple of competing ones, so you should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a shameless self promotion, but I extracted it into it's own gem: [RubyGems](https://rubygems.org/gems/mongoid-paranoia) / [GitHub](https://github.com/simi/mongoid-paranoia)